# Allow only one checkbox selected. 1 checkbox each in two independent forms, all on one page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I have a HTTP interface page that requires the user to upload various independent files.  For this I have created multiple tables that each have its own form.

In two of the tables I need one checkbox each that allows the user to select it which then requires that the file is installed on system startup.

Both tables are for uploading system firmware, one table for primary firmware, and the other for backup firmware.

The system will crash if both firmwares are being uploaded, hence separate forms.

Because of this crashing issue, for the two checkboxes it needs to be: One selected, or the other selected, or neither selected.

Here is a sample html code:

```
<body>

<div id="container"> 
 <table width="1000" border="0" cellpadding="1" class="uploadBox">
   <tr>
     <td width="460" rowspan="2">
      <form action="fileupload.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <b>Update Primary System Firmware</b>
        <p style="margin-bottom: 2px"> <b>File: </b>
          <input type="file" name="firmwaremain" size="30" />
          <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </p>


    </td>
    <td width="210" height="23">Current File Name:</td>
    <td width="117">Current File Size:</td>
    <td width="102">File Upload Date:</td>
    <td width="93">Install on Start</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>~curFirmName~</td>
    <td width="117">~curFirmSize~</td>
    <td width="102">~curFirmDate~</td>
    <td width="93"><input type="checkbox" name="firmPrim" id="firmPrim" /></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 </form>

 <table width="1000" border="0" cellpadding="1">
   <tr>
    <td width="460" rowspan="2">
     <form action="fileupload.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <b>Update Backup System Firmware</b>
        <p style="margin-bottom: 2px"><b>File: </b>
          <input type="file" name="firmwarebackup" size="30" /> 
          <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </p>

   </td>
   <td width="210" height="23">Current File Name:</td>
   <td width="117">Current File Size:</td>
   <td width="102">File Upload Date:</td>
   <td width="93">Install on Start</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>~curBackName~</td>
   <td width="117">~curBackSize~</td>
   <td width="102">~curBackDate~</td>
   <td width="93"><input type="checkbox" name="firmBackup" id="firmBackup" /></td>
 </table>
 </form>
</div>
```

As you can see, they checkboxes are in two independent forms, so it has been difficult for me to run a JavaScript code, since (I think) it calls for the checkboxes to be in one form.

Also I cant use radio buttons because they are in different forms, plus there has to be an option for neither to be selected.

Is there a way to validate the whole page and check all forms so that only one check box can be selected on the page?

Thanks!

Regards, 
Josh

Comment: the tildes (~) by the way are files that are passed to the webpage via c code and xml.

Comment: why not use a radio with a none option selected by default?

Comment: you can set a boolean to false and then search through both forms for the check checkboxes. if you find one checked set it to true. if you find a second one checked and the boolean is already true then call your error code (set them both unchecked or whatever you need to do)

Comment: they are in two different forms. Also, once selected the radio cannot be unselected unless you do a page refresh, which could cause a system crash

Comment: use a class on the checkboxes to target them and check through both forms separately but use one boolean

Comment: Nathan, I have tried but it wouldn't work. Furthest I have gotten is where both could be selected, but when you unselect the first box, it clears both.

Comment: try putting an id on the forms and select them based on form id and checkbox class. you are selecting both because its on the class. basically use both selectors at once instead of just the class.

Comment: best to give the checkboxes unique id's as well as ids are supposed to be unique

Comment: oh and name them differently too

Comment: whoops, they were, the second is firmBackup. something went wrong on my copy and paste :)

Comment: nevermind what gilly said will work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a click handler to both of the checkboxes that unchecks the checkbox in the other form if the clicked checkbox is checked:

```
var primCheck = document.forms[0].firmPrim;
var backCheck = document.forms[1].firmBackup;
primCheck.onclick = checkClick;
backCheck.onclick = checkClick;

function checkClick(e) {
    var otherCheckbox = this === primCheck ? backCheck : primCheck;
    if (this.checked) {
        otherCheckbox.checked = false;
    }
}
```

**Working Demo:** [jsfiddle.net/QM6sy/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/QM6sy/1/)

Comment: Gilly, I corrected the second CheckBOX ID name, does your code look like it should with the names I have?

Comment: @JoshC - Nope.  My code relied on the fact that you had your checkboxes named the same.  Just a moment and I'll update it to work with your differently named checkboxes.

Comment: @Josh - You can also prioritize the checkboxes when processing the form submits if they do both come across as checked, for example implement a rule that says "if both checkboxes are checked use the Primary System Firmware and ignore the other checkbox".  That way you'll be safe when I turn off javascript and screw with your form while attempting to find attack surfaces.

Comment: @Stephen P - how does that work with two forms and two submits, and that they're independent. Just wondering?

Comment: @JoshC - Note that you've got some issues with your HTML.  You have the `<form>` start tags within a `<td>`, but the end tags are outside of the table. This is invalid HTML. You should place the `<form>` start tag before the opening `<table>` tag. Also, most of those attributes on your table are deprecated in favor of CSS. You can remove the height, width, cellspacing, and cellpadding attributes.

Comment: @Gilly - Awesome man! Much appreciated! Thanks, I know this must have been mind numbing for you, but it means a lot. It is working like a charm!

Comment: @Gilly - i am getting this in the jsfiddle error checker: "Error:
Problem at line 10 character 20: 'checkClick' was used before it was defined.
function checkClick(e) {"

Comment: That warning from JSLint is not important. If you want it to go away, you can move the function declaration above the onload handler: http://jsfiddle.net/QM6sy/9/.  But, the warning is really meaningless - it's based on rules that someone decided were a good idea to follow when writing JavaScript. It won't make your code run faster or prevent errors. You'll find plenty of people disagreeing with some of the JSLint rules.